# How to combine two return params into one value

Tags: go, variadic

**What I have** many times in different versions in my code:

```
func f() (bool, bool) {
   value, successFulOperation := someStuff()
   return value, successFulOperation
}

// somewhere else
value, successfulOperation := f()
if value && successfulOperation {
  // do stuff
}
```

`// do stuff` should only be executed if `value` is true AND the operation that retrieved `value` succeeded without an error. In other words: I don't care about `value` or `successfulOperation`. I only care about `value && successfulOperation`.

**A solution I want to avoid (seems verbose):**

```
value, successfulOperation := f()
actualValue := value && successfulOperation
if actualValue {...}
```

Above code is really simplified. In reality the if conditions will be nested and more complicated.

**What I want:**

A wrapper for `f` that combines both values into one. How do I do that? The solution should work for any function taking any parameters and returning two bools.

The following does not work:

```
type doubleBoolFunc func(...interface{}) (bool, bool)

func and(fn doubleBoolFunc, params ...interface{}) bool {
    b1, b2 := fn(params...)
    return b1 && b2
}

actualValue := and(f())
```

Comment: your double bool returns seem very close the idiomatic Go pattern: `if v, err := fn(...); err != nil  { ... }` and really can't be simplified any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write a wrapper function to turn the two bools into one until generics are in the language in go 1.18<sup>1</sup>. Or at least you can, using reflect, but it's a mess.

But you can write this with go 1.17:

```
func both(x, y bool) bool {
    return x && y
}

func f() (bool, bool) {
    return true, false
}

func main() {
    r := both(f())
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

But more practical (in my opinion) is to eschew this complication, and use a 1-line if. Not everything needs to be a function or abstracted away:

```
if a, b := f(); a && b {
    ...
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Even when generics are introduced in go 1.18, I don't think there'll be a way to specific a generic type that represents a function with arbitrary arguments that returns two bools.

Comment: *a generic type that represents a function with arbitrary arguments* — indeed. the arbitrary args would have to be typed anyway, with or without type parameters, and the only possible catch-all vararg signature is `...interface{}`. or `...any`.

Comment: as a matter of fact, `[T any](...T)` will be even worse because then *all* varargs are restricted to whatever `T` is being inferred to.

Answer (score 0):

```
func and(a, b bool) bool {
  return a && b
}
```

then if f return 2 bool

```
value := and(f())
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code at the end of your question, don't invoke the function `f()`, simply reference the function name `f` and then list its args:

```
// actualValue := and(f(args...))
actualValue := and(f, args...)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/KAT2L58ZQy3